# Registering a HttpHandler for file types in sub-folders

Tags: web-config, httphandler

I'm running and ASP.net Web Forms web site (IIS 7.5) and I want to register a specific HTTP Handler for specific file types in a folder and its sub-folders.  For example, I want all requests for PDF documents residing in the /Downloads or /Library to be handled by my custom handler.

I have tried the following entry in Web.config...

```
<handlers>
   <add name="DownloadManager_Downloads" verb ="GET" path="/Downloads/*.pdf" type="DownloadManager, XXX" />
   <add name="DownloadManager_Library" verb ="GET" path="/Library/*.pdf" type="DownloadManager, XXX" />
</handlers>
```

But whilst this handles /Downloads/Test.pdf it does not handle /Downloads/Latest/Test.pdf

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I re-factored the original handler as an HttpModule.  This gave me full control over where the mechanism should/should not be invoked.